# How to get information about user related to last change for a module or item

Tags: 2sxc

Im developing a module that notify when a user make some change inside portal in any module, for now i have enabled some modules like html, dnnformandlist, etc, and I would like to add into that notification information about 2sxc, maybe somebody can help me with some guide about what type of query i can do to get the last change about an app module placed into a page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATM there is no built in feature for this.

Every entity has a Modified date, so you could query that using LINQ but I'm not sure if that will help much, as some pieces of data (let's say a tag on a blog) may have a change but you won't exactly be able to point to the page that's affected.

Other data like ContentBlocks (basically the unit of content like a Module, placed on a page) do match one or more pages, but it's hard to find them exactly.

Maybe you could provide more information as to what you will achieve - that may help me give you a better guidance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me tell you what im doing. I have a DNN scheduler that runs every hour, and basically gets all modules changed in the last hour. When you change content in 2sxc, Html, DnnFormAndList modules, DNN update LastModifiedDate field, so is easy to get modules recently modified. 

Now I just have the module changed and the tab for that module, but i would like to get some additional information about the 2sxc module like the user or what was the change. I need to know how to get relation between a module and 2sxc app item or content.

Comment: The data for this is there, but the APIs are not optimized for such a use case. So it would be quite difficult to do - I believe even I would need half a day or so, and I really know my backend ;). 
So unless you're a real C# pro and have some time to do this (or a budget to have us do it) I recommend that you don't prioritize this for now.

Comment: Thanks again, just last question, do we have some field in database in relation to dnn modules ?

Comment: The link is from the DNN modules (module settings) which contains an App reference and a content-block reference. So the 2sxc data doesn't link DNN, DNN links 2sxc.

Comment: Thanks iJungleBoy for the information, that was what I needed, i can get information from there. I will  let you know later when finish my module.